# Ошибка в процессе создания виртуального окружения в Python

Tags: python

При попытке создания виртуального окружения в подкаталоге проекта возникает ошибка

> Error: Command
> '['C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\my_prj\myvenv\Scripts\python.exe',
> '-m', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero
> exit status 1.

Пробовал через Pycharm (используя import venv, и через терминал), и visualstudio, и через командную строку windows. Везде одно и то же, создается необходимый каталог, но как неполный, возникает ошибка. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Можно полный листинг того что возвращается при запуске команды `python -m venv venv` в терминале?

Comment: pip install upgrade pip?

Comment: PS D:\Training\MyPrj> python -m venv myvenv
Error: Command '['D:\\Training\\MyPrj\\myvenv\\Scripts\\python.exe', '-m', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
PS D:\Training\MyPrj>

Comment: Обновил pip, не помогло, все та же ошибка